# Why does the logical operator doesn´t in my code? | Javascript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I started my coding journey one week ago and I´m currently trying to build a to-do-list.
My goal is that if there is no input in the title or text field of my to-do-list the browser should alert the user with "Please enter a task :)", but currently the browser dont alert the user instead the values from the text and title field get saved into the array even if they are empty. This is my code:

```
// SELECT ELEMENT
const form = document.getElementById("todoform");
const titleInput = document.getElementById("input-title");
const textareaInput = document.getElementById("textarea");
const button = document.getElementById("submit-task-btn");

// ARRAY WHERE TO-DO´S GET SAVED AS OBJECTS
let tasks = [];

// FORM SUBMIT
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    saveTask();
});

// SAVE TODO
function saveTask() {
    const titleValue = titleInput.value;
    const textareaValue = textareaInput.value;

// CHECK IF TO-DO IS EMPTY
const isEmpty = titleValue && textareaValue === "";

    if (isEmpty) {
        alert("Please enter a task :)");
    }
    
    else {
        const todo = {
            title : titleValue,
            text : textareaValue,
        }
    
        tasks.push(todo);
    
        console.log(tasks);
    }
}
```

If I leave the logical operant "&&" away and set the alert up for only one value it works, but not with both values. I thought the && operant means that both values has to be true. I want that if the user put´s in only one value title or text the value stil gets saved into the array. Only when both values are empty the alert should trigger. you can fork the full project here: https://github.com/Cyber-SW/To-Do-List.git

Ty for your help guys. I appretiate every answer.

Comment: No, you need `titleValue === "" && textareaValue === ""`

Comment: From you description *if there is no input in the title or text field* you would need `isEmpty = titleValue === "" || textareaValue === ""`, as you want both to be present. With `&&` it would be possible to have one of them empty and still the task would get added.